# EWS Calendar Attendees

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am working with the Exchange Web Service and am able to retrieve calendar events using the FindItem function. I have the function returning the IDOnly and making an additional call to GetItem to get all the properties. I am able to get everything I need with the exception of Attendees who are outside of the firm.

For example, if my company has john@abc.com and joe@abc.com email accounts and I have a calendar item with both, the EWS API is correctly returning both those are attendees.

However, if I create an event with john@abc.com and johnsmithxxxxx@gmail.com, the gmail address does not get returned in the API response even though it shows up within Outlook.  Is this by design or do I need to specify some additional parameter to have the EWS API return ALL attendees regardless if they have a mailbox on the exchange server or not?

Comment: Please show your code as well as the returned XML. I do not see that behavior - external recipients are returned as MailboxType = OneOff instead of Mailbox.

Comment: Dmitry, you are indeed correct. Must have been some issue with the 2 test events not saving to the exchange server, I tried to create additional events and it does return the XML with the external contacts.